# Why <Navigate to="" /> is not working but console.log("Authentication successful!"); is working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

```
import Typewriter from "typewriter-effect";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState } from "react";

const Login = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const handleUsernameChange = (event) => {
    setUsername(event.target.value);
  };

  const handlePasswordChange = (event) => {
    setPassword(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (username === "name" && password === "123") {
      // Authentication successful - redirect to home page
      console.log("Authentication successful!");
      return <Navigate to="/home" />;
    } else {
      // Authentication failed - display an error message
      console.log("Authentication failed!");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="flex justify-center items-center w-full h-screenw-full h-screen bg-gradient-to-r from-lime-700 via-orange-900 to-red-800">
      <div className=" w-[500px] h-[490px] text-white bg-black/20 rounded-2xl">
        <div className="w-[400px] py-10 mx-auto">
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="text-black">
            <label>
              Username:
              <input
                type="text"
                value={username}
                onChange={handleUsernameChange}
              />
            </label>
            <br />
            <label>
              Password:
              <input
                type="password"
                value={password}
                onChange={handlePasswordChange}
              />
            </label>
            <br />
            <button
            >
              Submit
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

The `console.log` is working for both if condition but `<Navigate to="/home" \>` is not working is there any way to resolve this error, tried return `<Navigate to="/home" \>` without using if statement and it works, its not working in if statement, why this happens? ‎ ‎

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't return JSX from a callback like this and expect it to be rendered and do anything. The `Navigate` component issues a declarative navigation action and must be rendered with the component render, e.g. part of the returned JSX from the function component.

If you want to invoke a navigation action from a callback then use the `useNavigate` hook and issue an imperative navigation action.

Example:

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom"; // <-- import hook

const Login = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate(); // <-- call hook

  ...

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (username === "name" && password === "123") {
      // Authentication successful - redirect to home page
      console.log("Authentication successful!");
      navigate("/home"); // <-- issue navigation action
    } else {
      // Authentication failed - display an error message
      console.log("Authentication failed!");
    }
  };

  ...
```